# ASP.NET GridView: How to retrieve decimal value from a cell at RowDataBound?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, cell

I have a Temperature column in my GridView and want to retrieve the temperature value in decimal at RowDataBound. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {

   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // say temparature field in column 3

        decimal temp = decimal.Parse(e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString()); 
}

}
```

In case it errors out saying "Input String was not in a correct format" then take a look at this document

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Eduardo_Sierra.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much. I kept on getting that error and didn't know what I did wrong. Now I know that's a cause and can investigate.